# TypeScript destructuring alias import?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5, destructuring

I use namespaces/modules for my application. We have a large application broken into several smaller "modules". They are all compiled together, so we have all references at all times. If i need to access module `x.y` from module `z` I can simply by using `x.y`. Howevever, I don't want to keep referencing `x`. Is there anyway I can destructure `x` into aliased names? For example (this doesn't work, hence my question):

```
import {y,a,b} = x;
```

instead of:

```
import y = x.y;
import a = x.a;
import b = x.b;
```

Is there something similar I can do to simplify my import aliasing of internal modules?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this exists at this time, however I just opened a proposal on the [TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript) repo asking for type destructuring from a namespace.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13816
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13135

Please go comment on these issues to get this in the language!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something similar I can do to simplify my import aliasing of internal module

If the *members* of the module you are *importing* are not modules (or a type) `import` will not work. Use `var` instead:

```
module x{
 // stuff
}
var {y,a,b} = x;
```

Comment: I need them as types. This will mainly be used for Interfaces.